# Proper way to handle single quote in dynamic sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, escaping, dynamic-sql, single-quotes

I have a dynamic sql query below to create a function, I replaced single quote with 4x single quotes, but it does not work.

```
EXEC(
'
CREATE  OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnGetNumberFromPCN
(
    @PCN VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN

        --Init
        DECLARE @Number BIGINT = NULL

        --Get
        SELECT @Number = CASE WHEN PATINDEX(''''%[^0-9]%'''',STUFF(V.YourString,1,PI.I-1,'''''''')) > 0 
                                 THEN CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(V.YourString,PI.I,PATINDEX''''%[^0-9]%'''',STUFF(V.YourString,1,PI.I-1,''''''''))-1))
                                 ELSE 0
                            END
        FROM (VALUES(@PCN),(@PCN))V(YourString)
             CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX''''%[1-9]'''', V.YourString)))PI(I)

        --Finally
        RETURN @Number
END
')
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just examine the generated SQL and you'll see the problem:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = '
CREATE  OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnGetNumberFromPCN
(
    @PCN VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN

        --Init
        DECLARE @Number BIGINT = NULL

        --Get
        SELECT @Number = CASE WHEN PATINDEX(''''%[^0-9]%'''',STUFF(V.YourString,1,PI.I-1,'''''''')) > 0 
                                 THEN CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(V.YourString,PI.I,PATINDEX''''%[^0-9]%'''',STUFF(V.YourString,1,PI.I-1,''''''''))-1))
                                 ELSE 0
                            END
        FROM (VALUES(@PCN),(@PCN))V(YourString)
             CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX''''%[1-9]'''', V.YourString)))PI(I)

        --Finally
        RETURN @Number
END
'
print @sql
--exec (@sql)
```

outputs

```
CREATE  OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnGetNumberFromPCN
(
    @PCN VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN

        --Init
        DECLARE @Number BIGINT = NULL

        --Get
        SELECT @Number = CASE WHEN PATINDEX(''%[^0-9]%'',STUFF(V.YourString,1,PI.I-1,'''')) > 0 
                                 THEN CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(V.YourString,PI.I,PATINDEX''%[^0-9]%'',STUFF(V.YourString,1,PI.I-1,''''))-1))
                                 ELSE 0
                            END
        FROM (VALUES(@PCN),(@PCN))V(YourString)
             CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX''%[1-9]'', V.YourString)))PI(I)

        --Finally
        RETURN @Number
END
```

which fails with

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fnGetNumberFromPCN, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near ''.
```

Comment: I used 2x single quotes too. But still failed.

Comment: Yes, but with a different error or error location, which you can find and fix in the same way.

Comment: Thank  you. I got it now.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Please add support for here-string or special quoting: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34385422-add-support-for-here-strings-i-t-sql  With introducing support of new languages - Python/R/Java(external scripts) this should be a must. Plus it will simplify ton of dynamic SQL - like in this example. Counting `'` and doubling them sometimes causes headaches and it is error-prone.